# How to make crx xpi generate a Firefox 12.0 compatible .xpi

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Firefox Add-on, I wrote it with the Add-on Builder, it worked in Firefox 11.0.  I copied the files into a set of directories on my hard drive and used cfx xpi of the Firefox Add-on SDK 1.6.1 to generate an .xpi and it worked it Firefox 11.0.  I edited my main.js in the Add-on Builder and downloaded the .xpi and it works in Firefox 12.0.  I modified the main.js on my hard drive, ran cfx xpi, and then when I tried to load the resulting .xpi, it says that it can't install because it is not compatible with Firefox 12.0.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Add-on SDK 1.6 uses these compatibility settings:

```xml
<em:minVersion>10.0</em:minVersion>
<em:maxVersion>12.0a2</em:maxVersion>
```

So the add-ons it produces by default will only be compatible with an alpha version of Firefox 12 but not the final release. You should take the [advise from the documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/guides/firefox-compatibility.html) and edit `python-lib/cuddlefish/app-extension/install.rdf`. It would make sense to use `14.*` as `maxVersion` because addons.mozilla.org already [lists it as a valid version](https://addons.mozilla.org/pages/appversions/).

**Update**: Current versions of the Add-on SDK have more sensible compatibility ranges. However, if you need to change them - starting with Add-on SDK 1.12 the file can be found under `app-extension/install.rdf` ([current documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/dev-guide/guides/firefox-compatibility.html)).

Comment: @RobertLouisMurphy: Did you check `maxVersion` in `install.rdf` inside the generated XPI file? It's a regular ZIP archive, so you should be able to open it by renaming it into `foo.zip`.

Comment: Yep, I checked, with 12.0, 12.*, 13.*, 14.* does not work, however the .xpi from cfx xpi works, the .xpi from cfx xpi --update-link http://www.multiculturalyp.com/multiculturalyp.xpi --update-url http://www.multiculturalyp.com/multiculturalyp.update.rdf does not work.

Comment: @RobertLouisMurphy: You probably need to clear the cache - Firefox will query http://www.multiculturalyp.com/multiculturalyp.update.rdf for update compatibility information. I guess that your browsing cache still has a version of that file saying `<em:maxVersion>12.0a2</em:maxVersion>`.

Comment: Tried clearing my cache, that didn't help.  Here is what I am trying to do:  build .xpi, then load it from my hard drive on the Add-on Manager Tab

Comment: Small update, as this is an semi old post:
with the current version (1.12) the install.rdf file is located at app-extension/install.rdf

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but complete doc about min/maxVersion of generated xpi and changing them [is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Firefox_Compatibility).